# tensorflow feed_dict with an array and not a single value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently trying using tensorflow to train a neural network for regression purposes, such that i can map my input to an output. The input consist an audio filed which has been sampled and framed, each frame has a certain output.

Storing of input (audio frames) (give as example as the actual data is pretty large):

```
[array([[frame],[frame],...,[frame]],dtype=float32), ...]
```

And the output is stored as:

```
[array([[  4.53255900e+01,  -9.82247700e+00,  -1.22920200e+00,
         -6.81728800e+00,  -8.23808400e+00,  -1.42367900e+01,
         -4.64904100e+00,  -1.49673100e+01,  -4.75058700e+00,
         -7.54071600e+00,   5.11365500e+00,   9.80618400e+00,
         -6.03554700e-01],....,[...]])]
```

This is my code:

```
number_of_examples = len(train_data)/2
train_set_data = train_data[:number_of_examples]
train_set_output = train_output_data[:number_of_examples]

test_set_data = train_data[number_of_examples:]
test_set_output = train_output_data[number_of_examples:]
############################# Training setup ##################################
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50

# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")
n_samples = train_set_data[0].shape[0]

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")


# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)


# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for i in range(len(train_set_data)):
            for (x, y) in (train_set_data[i], train_set_output[i]):
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

            #Display logs per epoch step
            if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
                c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_set_data, Y:train_set_output})
                print "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
                    "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b)

        print "Optimization Finished!"
        training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_set_data, Y: train_set_output})
        print "Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n'
```

Problem is I get a error message

```
File "tensorflow_datapreprocess_mfcc_extraction_rnn.py", line 191, in <module>
    for (x, y) in (train_set_data[i], train_set_output[i]):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I am not sure I understand the error message, is it saying that I can't pass an array or I have to pass single values instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (x, y) in (train_set_data[i], train_set_output[i])
```

is probably not doing what you think it is doing. Did you mean to use zip()?

Comment: no... I intend to take an array each time an feed it to tensorflow as input abd output nothing else.

Comment: so what values would you expect x, y to take on given ([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])?

Comment: Well. in my case I have two lists as stated above. 
I want x = [1,2,3,...,2048] and y = [1,2,3,...,13]

Comment: I haven't specified the length of the input anywhere?

Comment: `train_set_data` and `train_set_ouput` both have a certain data representation.. I am not sure what would be come out of by zipping them together

Comment: using `zip` gives me an pretty large error message, which i can't seem to decode properly

Comment: The reason why i use [i] is to get each set.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what your model is supposed to be doing. print x and y before calling sess.run(...) - are those values what you expect?

Comment: ... I am confused?.. Thought this was a simply a incorrect use of an for loop?.. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try to put yourself in the place of the people who are trying to help you. We can't run your code, you don't show us your full data set. You don't reply to "what happens when you do X?" This is obviously a homework assignment (because we see similar questions.) You don't even understand the problem well enough to describe it in a way we can help. Sorry, I have to give up for now.

Answer (score 0):

That script is not doing what you want, to do what you want use:

```
   ...
   for epoch in range(training_epochs):
       for (x, y) in zip(train_set_data, train_set_output):
           sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
     ...
```

Comment: strictly, his syntax is fine, it's the semantics that are wrong :) But I already told him to use zip(). Bit of confusion here.